# Google Analytics SDK 3.0 for iOS: Anonymize IPs

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Since the iOS SDK 3.0 of Google Analytics has been released, plenty of changes have been made with the API. There is one big problem we encounter that has to do with the anonymize IP feature.

In Germany one has to anonymize the IPs by law when using some tracking framework. With the previous version of the SDK (2.0) it worked like this:

```
tracker.anonymize = YES;
```

where `tracker` is an instance of `id<GAITracker>`.
Now with the version 3.0 one has to use the set method of the tracker:

```
[tracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:@"?????"];
```

The signature of the method is

```
- (void)set:(NSString *)parameterName
      value:(NSString *)value;
```

and that's the problem. What should the parameter value be? `@"YES"` or `@"NO"`? `@"ON"` or `@"OFF"`? `@"1"` or `@"0"`? Are these parameters case-sensitive?

There is no information about the `value` in the documentary. Does anyone know what parameter is correct to anonymize the IPs?

Comment: +1, Really good question. The docs ain't too thorough.

Comment: As I write below we can find sample to another BOOL requared API method in "Google Analytics SDK for iOS - Migrating to v3" (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration). Sample from the migration manual: [tracker set:kGAIUseSecure value:[@NO stringValue]];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work for me:

```
[tracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:[@NO stringValue]];
```

or

```
[tracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:[@YES stringValue]];
```

Comment: How do you know that it works, i.e., that the IPs are anonymized afterwards?

Comment: That is a good question. With the method I posted I also don't know if it is actually doing anything or not, but I included it in my code and Apple accepted it. I'm kind of dissapointed with Google for not providing better documentation.

By the way does my method or Merc's method work for you? For some reason Merc's didn't work for me.

Comment: In my opinion it is not a thing of Apple. For instance, in Germany the law says that you must anonymize the IPs. But how do I know if the IPs are actually anonymized? I really don't know if the methods work. Of course, the code compiles and everything but I don't know if the SDK acts correctly and anonymizes the IPs.

Comment: Sure, we can't check real IPs stored on google servers, but follow to sample in "Google Analytics SDK for iOS - Migrating to v3" ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/migration) looks like we should use this format. Sample from the migration manual: [tracker set:kGAIUseSecure value:[@NO stringValue]];

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error with `kGAIAnonymizeIp` because it's defined in `GAIFields.h`, which isn't normally imported.

First import the header:

```
#import "GAIFields.h"
```

Then set the value:

```
[tracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:[@YES stringValue]];
```

Answer (score 2):

`[tracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:@"1"];`

See the [Anonymize IP](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced#anonymizeIp) section of the Google Analytics iOS v3 SDK documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the following method:

```
[self.tracker set:@"kGAIAnonymizeIp" value:@"YES"];
```

If I did

```
 [self.tracker set:kGAIAnonymizeIp value:@"YES"];
```

like in the other answer on here, it gave me an error saying the kGAIAnonymizeIp is an undeclared identifier.

Not sure if what I did works or is even doing anything but at least I tried. The documentation for analytics is really poor.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Google Analytics 4 from its [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9019185?hl=en#IP):

> In Google Analytics 4, IP anonymization is not necessary since IP
> addresses are not logged or stored.